# Append large lists in python2.7

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to plot a graph with the points ([0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,2],...[255,255,255]) on x-axis for that i am using list:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
x=[]
for i,j,k in product(xrange(256), repeat=3):
    x.append([i,j,k])
y=[]
for count in x:
   y.append(probability[count]) # this is how my probability array is stored

pylab.figure(0)
pylab.plot(x,y,'b')
pylab.show()
```

This idea I have borrowed from previous posts. I am new to python, so please help. The question is the above code gives "Memory Error". Can someone provide an efficient way to append elements to 'x'

Comment: The question is that the above code gives memory error. So, can someone suggest an efficient way to append elements to x or some other efficient manner to plot

Comment: You're creating about 256^3 * 4 bytes worth of objects, not to mention the overhead for each list created in the `append()`.  It's only practical to use Python for things that take up only *so* much memory.  Is there any specific reason as to *why* you're doing this, and is there a more efficient way than going through all 16 million values?

Comment: The reason being, I have to plot these many points on the graph

Comment: Respectfully, you probably don't need to plot that many points on the graph.  You need to plot enough to capture the important features of the data, including the fluctuations in the less important regions, and I very, very much doubt that you need 17M data points to achieve that.  If you insist you do, that's fine, but then matplotlib probably isn't the tool for you.  You'll start running into Agg rendering limits before that, I expect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I don't think pylab.plot does what you think it does, are you trying to display a surface in 3d?

Second, you should really be using ndarrays and not lists for something this big. I believe matplotlib will convert your lists to ndarrays anyway so you're better off starting with arrays. I think something like the following is what you want.

```
x, y, z = np.mgrid[0:256, 0:256, 0:256]
```

And last, what is `y` and what is `probability`? I ask because `probability[x[count]]` looks highly suspect to me, I think maybe you meant `probability[count]` but even so, if `probability` is a list, that should not work and if it is an array it'll blow up and could be causing your memory error. (Can't know for sure without the trace).

Take a look at the [Matplotlib Gallery](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html), their examples come with code and are very helpful for getting things working.

Comment: Yes u r correct its probability[count] and i have corrected that in my post..thanks. Also, I have to plot those many points on my array...though now i have reduced the points..but still its giving me error

Comment: Please tell us what you're trying to do. I suspect if you try plotting just a (5,5,5) part of your data you'll see that your code isn't doing what you think it is doing. I don't think `probability[count]` is right either, like I said in my answer that will not work if `probability` is a list and it'll blow up if `probability` is an array.

Answer (score 4):

With your current approach, `x` will have 16777216 (256<sup>3</sup>) elements in it.  Are you sure that you need to plot this many points on a graph?  If not, consider taking some sample of it, for example you could cut it down to 4096 samples by simply replacing `xrange(256)` with `xrange(0, 256, 16)`.

If matplotlib can plot iterables instead of lists you could save on the memory by doing that instead of creating the lists, it might look something like this:

```
from itertools import product, imap

def get_probability(count):
    return probability[x[count]]   # this code is broken, but from your example

x = product(xrange(256), repeat=3)
y = imap(get_probability, product(xrange(256), repeat=3))
pylab.plot(x, y, 'b')
```

As I pointed out in a comment above, `x[count]` will fail in the following code from your example:

```
for count in x:
    y.append(probability[x[count]])
```

This is because `x` is a list of lists, so `count` will always be a list like `[0, 0, 0]`, so in the first step of the loop you would attempt `x[[0, 0, 0]]` and get a `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list`.

Comment: Since get_probability is a function, so what value is being passed to count parameter here??? I am new to python so please explain..this may sound a naive question, still please explain. And thanks a ton for helping

Comment: @user1172532, count is an element from `x`. Try: `for x in ['a','b','c']: print(x)` in a Python shell. A `for` in python is more like a `foreach` in other languages you might be familiar with.

Comment: @user1172532 - Take a look at the documentation for [`imap`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap).  `get_probability` will be called for each element that is generated by `product`.

Comment: I tried the above approach but it is giving me "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number" error...can u please help me figure it out

Comment: @user1172532 - You would need to post some more code, there is no `float()` call anywhere here that could cause that error.

Answer (score 0):

Does `x` have to be a list of lists? Could it be a list of tuples?

If it can then you could simplify it to this:

```
x = list(product(xrange(256), repeat=3))
```

Comment: That's still 2**24 elements though, takes up 1.5GB in a second on my machine.

Comment: a numpy ndarray (np.empty((256,256,256), dtype=int)) is the better data structure.